# add  array keys with span tags

Tags: jquery

i have an array like:

```
var totalNum = new Array('img', 'img', 'img', 'img');
```

now on the `documentready` i added a `div` in the html page like:

```
$('#mainid').after('<div id="button"></div>');
```

the problem is i want to add `<span></span>` tags with total numbers in `totalNum` array like:

```
<div id="button">
   <span>1</span>
   <span>2</span>
   <span>3</span>
   <span>4</span>
</div>
```

i tried with `for(){}` loop into the `.after()` but got the syntax error. My code is here:

```
jQuery('#mainid').after('<div id="button">' + 
        for(i=1;i<=totalNum.length;i++){
    jQuery('<span>'+i+'</span>').appendTo('#button');
}
    + '</div>');
```

Comment: #button and #jp-button aren't the same divs

Comment: @SeanCarruthers sorry now changed, it was a copy paste by me.

Comment: Alright, was just making sure that wasn't your problem :)

Comment: @SeanCarruthers Thanks for your quick reply. yes i am sure that was not my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
jQuery('#mainid').after('<div id="button"></div>');

for(i=1;i<=totalNum.length;i++){
    jQuery('<span>'+i+'</span>').appendTo('#button');
}
```

OR

```
var tmpStr = '';
for(i=1;i<=totalNum.length;i++){
    tmpStr += '<span>'+i+'</span>';
}

jQuery('#button').append(tmpStr);
```

This would be a better approach to prevent the syntax error & append.

Answer (score 2):

You can't throw a `for` loop in the middle of string concatenation.

```
var button = $('#button');

$.each(totalNum, function(index) {
    $('<span />', { text: index + 1 }).appendTo(button);
});
```

I believe this has some benefits such as...

- Not forcing the browser to parse HTML.
- Caching a reference to the target element `#button`.
- `$.each()` to me is more elegant than an explicit `for` loop.

Answer (score 1):

You can't concatenate a for loop like that! Also you forgot to declare `i`. Then is recomended to cache the length and append all html strings in a variable and append to object at last to avoid stressing the DOM as much as possible. You can do this:

```
var spans = ''; 
for (var i=1, len=totalNum.length; i<len; i++) {
    spans += '<span>'+ i +'</span>';
}
$('<div id="button">').append(spans).appendTo('#mainid');
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `map` function to loop the array as an expression, and use `join` to concatenate the array items into a single string:

```
jQuery('#mainid').after(
  '<div id="button">' + 
  jQuery.map(totalNum, function(e,i){ return '<span>'+(i+1)+'</span>'; }).join('') +
  '</div>'
);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/U48yP/

Comment: wow, i didn't knew about this. but 'linuxeasy's answer also worked for me. But thanks a lot to aware about the `.map()` +1 ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try just:

```
jQuery('#mainid').after('<div id="button"></div>');

for( i=1; i<=totalNum.length; i++ ) {
   jQuery('#button').append('<span>' + i + '</span>');
}
```

I switched from .appendTo to .append, because that just seemed like an indirect way of doing things. This is a little more clear as to what we're doing.